# ASMX Web Service contém algum evento para o fim da requisição?

Tags: c#, web-service

Eu gostaria de fazer com que no fim de todas as requisições ao meu Web Service o SaveChanges fosse executado. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode implementar um IHttpModule, ou então usar os eventos do HttpApplication para isso.

**IHttpModule**

```
public class MeuModuloHttp : IHttpModule
{
    public String ModuleName
    {
        get { return "MeuModuloHttp"; }
    }

    public void Init(HttpApplication application)
    {
        application.EndRequest += (new EventHandler(this.Application_EndRequest));
    }

    private void Application_EndRequest(Object source, EventArgs e)
    {
        var application = (HttpApplication)source;
        var context = application.Context;
        if (context.Request.Url.AbsolutePath.EndsWith(".asmx"))
        {
            // executar algo
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}
```